# JSON data webscraping

Tags: python, html, json, python-requests

I am attempting to scrape job titles from [here](https://jobs.epicor.com/search-jobs).

Using Beautifulsoup I can scrape Job Titles from the first page. I am not able to scrape Job titles from the remaining pages. Using the Developertool > network I understood content type is JSON.

```
import requests
import json
import BeautifulSoup
from os import link
import pandas as pd
s = requests.Session()
headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'sec-ch-ua': '^\\^',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.101 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Referer': 'https://jobs.epicor.com/search-jobs',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
}
url=’https://jobs.epicor.com/search-jobs/results?ActiveFacetID=0&CurrentPage=2&RecordsPerPage=15&Distance=50&RadiusUnitType=0&Keywords=&Location=&ShowRadius=False&IsPagination=False&CustomFacetName=&FacetTerm=&FacetType=0&SearchResultsModuleName=Search+Results&SearchFiltersModuleName=Search+Filters&SortCriteria=0&SortDirection=1&SearchType=5&PostalCode=&fc=&fl=&fcf=&afc=&afl=&afcf=’
response = s.get(url, headers=headers).json()
data=json.dumps(response)
#print(data)
d2=json.loads(data)
for x in d2.keys():
  print(x)
###from above json results how to extract “jobtiltle”
```

The issue is above result's JSON data contains Html tags.  In this case how to scrape job titles from the JSON data?

Would really appreciate any help on this.

I am unfortunately currently limited to using only requests or another popular python library.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If the job titles is all that you need from your response text:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# your code here
soup = BeautifulSoup(response["results"])
for item in soup.findAll("span", { "class" : "jobtitle" }):
    print(item.text)
```

To navigate over the pages, if you hover your mouse cursor over the Prev or Next buttons there, you will see the url to request data from.